# Winding number of points on a path

Tags: complex-analysis, winding-number

I know that for $|z| = 1$ circular path with counter-clockwise rotation, the winding number of any point within the circle is 1(or more if the path is circulated more than 1 time. and also negative if the  rotation is clockwise). But what if the point was on the path? what would be the winding number then. Thus I am curious about 2 cases:

1. Winding number of p when p is on the $|z| = 1$ circle(counter-clockwise).
2. Winding number of p when p is on the $|z| = 1$ circle and also there is another $|z| = 2$ circle. Both counter-clockwise direction and
3. Same as 2, but for opposite directions.

Comment: The winding number of a path around a point isn't defined if the point is on the path.